# How to write an insert SQL statement that loop through each record in an array of objects and insert into a record's specific columns accordingly?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

First of all, I wanted to figure out how to even write an array of objects (like in js) in sql statement, and I am found nothing on the internet...

I can certainly just repeating all the insert statement, but I really just want to loop through a dataset and inject them into a table for a set of columns with exactly the same insert statement with different value! But seems there is no way to do this if the dataset is too complicated like an array of objects? or do I have to just write multiple list of arrays to represent each column which is really silly.. no?

Thanks

Example of data set

```
[
  {
    name: 'abc',
    gender: 'male',
  },
  {
    name: 'bbc',
    gender: 'female',
  },
  {
    name: 'ccc',
    gender: 'male',
  },
]
```

and put them into a table with columns of

```
nameHere
genderThere
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the followup, I added a example on what I try to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements` to extract each JSON from the array, then use that as the source for an INSERT:

```
create table x(name text, gender text);

insert into x (name, gender)
select t ->> 'name', t ->> 'gender'
from jsonb_array_elements(
'[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "name": "bbc",
    "gender": "female"
  },
  {
    "name": "ccc",
    "gender": "male"
  }
]'::jsonb) t;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/GZF87679

Update (after the scope changed)

To deal with nested JSON structures, you need to combine the operator that returns `jsonb` `->` with the one that returns "plain text":

```
insert into x (name, gender)
select t -> 'name' ->> 'first', t ->> 'gender'
from jsonb_array_elements(
'[
  {
    "name": {"first": "a", "last": "b"},
    "gender": "male"
  }
]'::jsonb) t;
```

More details about the JSON operators can be found [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: wooooooo that's fancy! just a bit more curious. what if the array have one more level of nesting let say data of `{
    name: {first: 'a', last: 'bc'},
    gender: 'male',
  },` can you some how able to target `first` and `last` nested object? is that just add another `->>` after `'name'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from json_each( (REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( your_input,  '},{' , ' ' )  ,'[','{') ,']','}'))::json)
```

this will output a table

```
  name | gender
  -----+-------
  abc  | male
  bcc  | female 
  ccc  | male
```

you can insert it in any table you want